# Is there an alternative function which does the same thing as clip raster by masked layer on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, geotiff-tiff, multi-band, extract-by-mask

I am having some technical problems with the clip raster by masked layer and I faintly remember using a different method a long time ago for a similar problem. Anybody familiar with another function?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general tip for when you're looking for a tool, when you have some idea what it does but you don't know what it's called.

Open the Processing Toolbox panel, and enter a short keyword into the search bar.

I searched for "clip" and found the following tools. According to the section headers, you can see which tools are for vectors and which ones are for rasters.

[image]

The GDAL tool `Clip raster by mask layer` is the one you already tried (it's also accessible through the Raster menu). Try the SAGA tool `Clip raster with polygon`.